# How to disable v-tooltip when user click outside

Tags: vue.js

I use v-tooltip to show tooltip on every cell of table

```
<td v-tooltip="{content: 'some content', trigger: 'click'}"></td>
```

But I want when user click another cell, current tooltip will disapear, I have tried "autoHide" property, but it not working.

[image]

Thanks

v-tooltip repository:
https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip

Comment: Have you tried `VTooltip.options.autoHide = true`?

Comment: @samayo : how to use this option? I have tried this: <td v-tooltip="{contentn: 'some content', trigger: 'click', autoHide: true}"></td> But it not working

Comment: You can use it after you do `import VTooltip ...` then below it do `VTooltip.options.autoHide = true`

Comment: I have tried: add VTooltip.options.autoHide = true; after import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip' but it show message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'autoHide' of undefined

Comment: Maybe use `trigger: 'focus'` instead of `click` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use the more customizable `v-popover` component. The `v-tooltip` directive doesn't seem to handle `manual` triggering, and you need manual triggering.

```js
console.clear();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    selectedCell: null
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 42px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px 4px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  right: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tooltip[aria-hidden='true'] {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s, visibility .15s;
}

.tooltip[aria-hidden='false'] {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/v-tooltip"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <tr v-for="i in 3">
      <td @click="selectedCell = i">
        <p><span>This is cell {{ i }}</span></p>
        <v-popover trigger="manual" :open="selectedCell === i">
          <template slot="popover">
            <p>
              {{ message }}
            </p>
          </template>
        </v-popover>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for solution, i solved this problem by set trigger: 'focus' and set tab-index for td element

Comment: I'm using vuetify 2.x and v-popover seems best suited for this imo. Just spent 2 hours trying to make v-tooltip work =(   THanks man

Answer (score 1):

It's a late answer but maybe it can help someone else:

you can add the tooltip component as a ref and call the `hide` method:

`this.$refs.popover.hide()`